Can A Fairy Fly With A Magical Breastplate Weighing 10 lbs?
According to Monsters of the Multiverse, the fairy's flight trait is described on page 14 as follows:

Flight: Because of your wings, you have a flying speed equal to your
walking speed. You can't use this flying speed if you're wearing
medium or heavy armor.

However, there is a reward in Adventurers League DDEP00-02 The Red War: Tier 2 which is a magical breastplate described as follows:

This surprisingly light breastplate is made of smoky red glass as
strong as steel. Barely translucent, when light strikes it the smoky
inclusions in the glass seem to shift and flow. The breastplate weighs
10 lbs.

For comparative purposes, according to the PHB, studded leather armor, which can be worn while flying, weighs 13 lbs.
Does this mean that a fairy can fly with this magical breastplate which weighs only 10 lbs?

No
RAW, weight isn't mentioned in the Fairy's Flight trait description. It simply says that it doesn't work if you're wearing medium or heavy armour.
A DM could infer that it's likely because of the weight that justifies why the Fairy's Flight trait says that, and can house rule that this medium armour that is very light (in terms of weight) can bypass the Fairy's trait's restriction, but that would be a houserule. (As an alternative line of reasoning, it could be due to the shape of medium/heavy armour and that it is less flexible compared to light armour, and thus prevents flying, so it might not even be due to the weight at all).
